# Commerce Server Catalog Manager - 8.2.1

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-catalog, commerce-server

I am installing the `Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1 Update 2`.

Installing the Adventure Works Front Store it my Catalog was not installed.

Just like described here: [Issues while installing commerce - Entity Adventure Works Catalog|AW535-11| was not found](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4728/issues-while-installing-commerce-entity-adventure-works-catalogaw535-11-was) I know there is a bug and I have to IMPORT the catalog manually.

Problem is: 
When I open my `Commerce Server Catalog Manager` I don't see any tasks. 
No options to import.

[image]

Why is my `Commerce server Catalog Manager` like this?

**Details:**

Opening the Catalog manager my connection points to:

http://csservices:1004/CFSolutionStorefrontsite_CatalogWebService/CatalogWebService.asmx
[image]

From Browser I see the CatalogWebService is fine:
[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: it should help you: https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/6/t/3644

Comment: Did you check the authentication as mentioned in the community post above?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to import through the File - Import Product Catalog menu.
This is a post I wrote on how to import the catalog xml file
https://sitecorebrasil.wordpress.com/2017/05/18/sitecore-commerce-adventure-works-catalog-did-not-get-imported-how-to-do-that-manually/

Also I remember I had an issue with permissions on the CSServices site on IIS when running this locally so you might want to check your IIS permissions.
This is what you should be looking for:

CSService - Windows Authentication and Anonymous authentication enabled

Catalog - Windows Authentication enabled and anonymous disabled

Profiles - Windows authentication enabled and anonymous disabled

This did the trick for me. Hope this helps

Comment: that didn't help so far. The import catalog option is still disabled. All authentication settings are as you suggested

Comment: Have you tried chaning the app pool user? Does the user you are trying to login using windows authentication have proper permissions meaning maybe you can try with an admin user and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: on my apppool for CSServices the identity is set to .\CSFndRuntimeUser this is admin user of the machine.

Comment: I am re-installing all from beginning. Something must be wrong with the service

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue 
it was resolved by adding my local windows account to the `CatalogAdministrator and Administrator roles`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

We have run into same problems last year when working with Sitecore Commerce  8.2.1 when we logged into Windows with non-admin account.

Root cause of this problem is with access rights that are defined using [Authorization Manager (AzMan)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/25c78a/use-authorization-manager-azman-for-managing-roles-and-per/).

Commerce Server Catalog Manager accesses the Commerce Server Catalog Web services using Windows Authentication. Therefore when you start Sitecore Commerce Catalog Manager it accesses the Web services with the user account you are currently logged into Windows.

It is working in browser just fine as the interface uses CSFndRuntimeUser to access webservices.

You need to add your local Windows/domain user using Authorization Manager, to the CatalogAuthorizationStore.xml file that's in the Catalog webservices folder as an administrator.

Even though [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/maxakbar/2006/10/15/simplifying-authorization-management-of-commerce-server-web-services/) was written in 2006 it really helped us.

**Steps to follow to fix your problems:**

1. Open Authorization Manager (Run azman.msc from command prompt)
2. Open "CatalogAuthorizationStore.xml" file by right clicking on  "Authorization Manager" root and clicking on "Open Authorization Store...":

   [image: azman]
3. In next dialog, select "XML file" as store type and click "Browse" button. Navigate to folder where you have installed Commerce Server Catalog Web Services. For us it was "C:\inetpub\CSServices\CFSolutionStorefrontsite_CatalogWebService":

[image: azman selecting xml file]

4. Select "CatalogAuthorizationStore.xml" file.
5. In the tree on the left, navigate to **CatalogAuthorizationStore.xml > CatalogandInventorySystem > Role Assignments > Administrator**
6. Right click on "Administrator" and select "Assign Users and Groups" and then "From Windows and Active Directory"

[image: azman administrator]

7. Choose your user and you are good to go
8. Restart machine (just to be sure :-)) Can't recall whether this was mandatory or not.